# Django BooleanField default for mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am using Django 1.7 with MySQL.

I have an existing model that I want to add a BooleanField to. I want the field to default to true. Seems simple enough right? So I create my field like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Then I run `makemigrations` and I get the following migration generated:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='mymodel',
        name='myfield',
        field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
        preserve_default=True,
    ),
]
```

Looks legit, however when I apply the migration the field created in my database does not have the default value, it looks like this:

`my_field tinyint(1) NOT NULL,`

Now, when I apply the migration existing records have the field set to 1 but what I want is for the migration to create a field that defaults to true, or 1. What am I missing here? Could anyone shed some light on what I am doing incorrectly? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks much!

Comment: What happens when you create a new entry in MyModel, and save it?  Does it set my_field to True?

Comment: @joelgoldstick - yes, however the nature of the code base I am working with doesn't always use the ORM(we are transitioning to Django but there is still legacy code), that's why I want the default to be set at the db level

Comment: So, it seems django is doing the right thing, but the legacy code is added new records that don't default.  Sorry, I can't think of a way around that.  Maybe run a cron job that updates new records from your legacy code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django never sets the default on a database level. If you want to support the default in legacy code, you can add a [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) operation to your migration that adds the default to the database column.